# Why does this switch take 2 clicks to turn back to the other side?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, local-storage

I'm loading/saving a state for light/dark mode in localstorage, and calling it to a Chakra UI switch, where if its on dark mode(aka turned "on") then the switch will already be on, dark mode, etc. If its in light mode (aka turned "off") then the switch will be turned on the left, however, when I turn the switch on, it takes two clicks to turn back to the left (even though its switching themes)

Demo of problem:
https://streamable.com/3wg7xe

Loading/Saving Data:

```
    const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");


    const toggleTheme = () => {
        setTheme((curr) => (curr === "light" ? "dark" : "light"));
    };

    const saveState = (state) => {
        toggleTheme();
        var status = '';
        if(state === "light") {
            status = "dark";
        } else {
            status = "light";
        }
        
        try {
            const currState = JSON.stringify(status)
            localStorage.setItem('theme', currState)
        } catch(err) {
            return undefined;
        }
    }

    const loadState = (state) => {
        try {
            const loadState = localStorage.getItem(state)
            if(loadState === null) {
                return undefined;
            }
            return JSON.parse(loadState)
        } catch(err) {
            return undefined;
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        setTheme(loadState('theme'))
    }, []);
```

Conditional render for button:

```
{theme === 'dark' ? <Switch onChange={() => saveState(theme)} isChecked id="theme-toggle"/> : <Switch onChange={() => saveState(theme)} id="theme-toggle"/>}
```

Comment: Why you do `JSON.stringify(status)` if `status` is already string?

Comment: its always been a habit to stringify it, so i was just going through the motions when i wrote the function.

Comment: you are using two different switches.. thats why it updates in the second click ..i have created a minimistic solution for you in this codesandbox..  https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-star-2esnnm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: In `toggleTheme` your `curr` is always _undefined_, unless you set it somewhere outside this example